# How to show my office location using Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have already pointed my office location in google map.

Also I created  API key.

Now i using embeded code to show google map location in my contact page.

I want to replace the same with AP key.

How to show my office location using  Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

Following is my test.html page for checking the map. Which parts need to modify to show my location ?

You can see my location in below url

google(dot)com/maps?ll=9.965156,76.290034&z=14&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=embed&cid=9383043750302267720

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my key already added here">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -9.959238, lng: 76.275271},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to [add a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add)

Code below is for your `initialize` function based on the docs but w/ your Lat,Lon and zoom level.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(9.965156,76.290034);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

// To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World"
});
```

The marker's title (i.e. "Hello World" in the example above) will appear as a tooltip.  If you don't want a tooltip, you can remove that line.

Comment: Thank you.
But its showing PLACE NAME (KOCHI).
Not my office location

I need like the below image

http://imgur.com/gXXLHHy

Comment: following is my location, how to add this using Map API    

https://www.google.com/maps/place/HostOnNet.com,+Venus+Chambers,+Valanjambalam/@9.9816358,76.2998842,11z/data=!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x0:0x82374493d0b73948!2sHostOnNet.com,+Venus+Chambers,+Valanjambalam!3m1!1s0x0:0x82374493d0b73948?hl=en-US/data=!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x0:0x82374493d0b73948!2sHostOnNet.com,+Venus+Chambers,+Valanjambalam!3m1!1s0x0:0x82374493d0b73948?hl=en-US